# One Drive Personal and One Drive for Business - how to remove personal setup prompt?

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, office365

My organisation recently set up ODB for us to use. After installing it, every time I open my ODB folder, I get the following prompt:

[image]

This is a prompt from One Drive Personal, as in the notification area at that point I have two onedrive icons:

[image]

How can I uninstall/Disable the Personal OneDrive, whilst keeping ODB?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm running Windows 7, as shown by tagging the question with "windows-7"

Comment: Then it removes the ODB connectivity also, as far as I can see. When I uninstalled OneDrive, I no longer had any onedrive connectivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following action resolved it:

1. Navigate to C:\Users\
2. Delete the "OneDrive" folder that exists there (not the one used by ODB, there is another one)
3. The issue no longer occurs

Answer (score 2):

> ### Prevent users from synchronizing personal OneDrive accounts
>
> The *Prevent users from configuring personal OneDrive accounts* policy
>   allows you to blocks users from syncing files from consumer (Microsoft
>   Account based) OneDrive. **By default, users are allowed to synchronize
>   personal OneDrive accounts.**
>
> If you enable this setting, users will be prevented from setting up a
>   sync relationship for their personal OneDrive account. If they had
>   previously been synchronizing a personal OneDrive account, they are
>   shown an error when they start the sync client, but their files remain
>   on the disk.
>
> **If you disable this setting, users are allowed to synchronize personal
>   OneDrive accounts.**

You can find this policy under:

`User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\OneDrive`

> Before you can begin administering OneDrive with group policy, you
>   must download the [OneDrive Deployment Package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=717805) and add the
>   OneDrive.admx and OneDrive.adml files to your group policy central
>   store.

[Administrative settings for the new OneDrive sync client](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Administrative-settings-for-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-0ecb2cf5-8882-42b3-a6e9-be6bda30899c)

> How can I uninstall/Disable the Personal OneDrive, whilst keeping ODB?

Have an Administrator on the Active Domain disable the **Prevent users from configuring personal OneDrive accounts** policy.  If they have not loaded the OneDrive active domain policy templates, they will have to do that, before the policy can be set.

To remove the OneDrive-personal icon on File Explorer:

> Note: It only works when you already have OneDrive-personal icon
>   appear on File Explorer.
>
> 1. Press windows key+R to open Run dialog box.
> 2. Type regedit.exe then press enter to open registry editor.
> 3. Go to the following location: `hkey_current_user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\desktop\namespace`
> 4. Find the subkey for OneDrive personal. Usually, it is **{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}**. But it is OK if different.
> 5. Go to the following location: hkey_classes_root\clsid
> 6. Find the key that matches OneDrive personal which you find in step 4.
> 7. In the subkey **system.ispinnedtonamespacetree** change the value date from 1 to **0**.
> 8. Save the change.

[How to turn off/hide OneDrive Personal but leave OneDrive Business on](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_o365app/how-to-turn-offhide-onedrive-personal-but-leave/bea35a10-78e9-4b35-a5df-c69060ad509b)

**Author's Warning**:
*You should backup the registry key before you delete it.  If you don't know what you are doing, you should get somebody who does, and they should modify the registry instead.  If you do not heed my warnings then you are on your own.*

Comment: It might be as simple as just removing the icon, personally, I would do both actions.